# Start Windows 10 in safe mode without keyboard

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, safe-mode

After an Windows 10 PC (Intel i7 10700, Gigabyte B460) update my wireless keyboard and mouse no longer work. I know its a driver problem because this same wireless mouse and keyboard work on another Win10 Surface PC.

When I plug a cabled mouse in and it powers up the mouse on start up, then at the Ctrl+Alt+Delete login screen Windows cuts the mouse's power. If I start up in Diagnostic mode the cabled mouse does work, I just get stuck at this next step needing a keyboard and all the instructions to get into Safe Mode require one:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get into Safe Mode without a Keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a keyboard (more than a mouse) because in any mode (including Safe Mode) you need to log in.

So see if you can borrow a plug in keyboard from some one.

Given your description, you have stalled predictably, so a plug in keyboard is the only way at this point.

**UPDATE:**

If you only have a mouse the only way is to use System Restore Points. Otherwise you need a keyboard. Note: if you're having trouble with **USB Keyboard/Mouse** get a **PS2** as the problem is to do with USB drivers.

Comment: You can't think of a way to enable the OSK in the Diagnostic mode?

Comment: You need a keyboard for most input especially when you go to log in and then update drivers.

Comment: @JeremyThompson - The OSK isn’t an option at the point in your screenshot and on modern versions of Windows that’s the only way of booting to Safe Mode other than modifying your BCD.  However, that requires a working keyboard, and Windows must normally boot

Comment: Talk about a catch-22, looks like I'll be door knocking for an old PS2 keyboard...

Comment: I don't know what type of computer you have but you mention PS2. Older BIOSs had a setting that enabled USB keyboards/mouse in boot which on even older BIOSs was disabled by default.